# Полупрозрачность окна

Tags: c++

Хочу сделать полупрозрачное окно, делаю задний фон белым, прозрачный цвет - белым и получается белое по краям. Использую *png файл с альфаканалом. Как сделать нормально?

![alt text][1]
[1]: http://s44.radikal.ru/i104/1307/80/31077b1a4759.jpg
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Из показанного на данный момент непонятно как именно вы делаете сейчас.
Вам надо полноценное Layered-окно. Всё окно как единый битмап, с альфа-каналом, премультированными RGB (на альфу). Гуглите "Layered Windows".

Comment: Будут конкретные сложности - спрашивайте. Можно прямо тут.